# Why does tableview works fine on iOS 6+ simulator but in iOS 5 simulator it crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using below code - **UITableViewDataSource** Methods as follows:

**numberOfRowsInSection**

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [dataArray count];
}
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = dataArray[indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But in iOS 5, to create instance of UITableViewCell we generally use this method :-

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

In iOS 5, there is no need of extra parameter which you have used in iOS 6. Just drop it and it will work (forIndexPath:).

Answer (score 2):

Without error message is hard to say. 
But I think error related to  `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` because this method available only on iOS 6.0 and later. See more in Apple doc [https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier%3aforIndexPath%3a)

Comment: i am unable to find - then whats the solution

Comment: use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` instead (version without index path)